# r plyr revalue limitation of number of operations?

Tags: r, plyr

I'm currently using revalue() from plyr to revalue factors levels in a dataframe from a code, like A01-21 to the real value. There are around 2400 levels, and I want revalue in order to be able to have the code as reference in my dataframe, and the corresponding values in translatable texts (to show them in french in french web pages, etc...)

You can test this yourself :

First create a dataframe:

```
test <- c("H07-24", "H07-25", "H07-26", "H07-27", "H07-28", "H07-29", "H07-30", "H07-31", "H07-32", "H07-33", "H07-34", "H07-35", "H07-36", "H07-37", "H07-38", "H07-40", "H07-41", "H07-42", "H07-43", "H07-44", "H07-45", "H07-46", "H07-47", "H07-48", "H07-49", "H07-50", "H07-51", "H07-52", "H07-53", "H07-54", "H07-55", "H07-56", "H07-57", "H07-60", "H07-61", "H07-62", "H07-63", "H07-64", "H07-65", "H07-66", "H07-67", "H07-68", "H07-69", "H07-70", "H07-71", "H07-72", "H07-73", "H07-74", "H07-75", "H07-80", "H07-81", "H07-82", "H07-83", "H07-84", "H07-85", "H07-86", "H07-90", "H07-91", "H07-92", "H07-93", "I00-00", "I01-00", "I01-10", "I01-11", "I01-12", "I01-13", "I01-20", "I01-21", "I01-22", "I01-23", "I01-24", "I02-00", "I02-10", "I02-10", "I02-11", "I02-12", "I02-20", "I02-21", "I02-22", "I02-23", "I02-24", "I02-40", "I02-40", "I03-00", "I03-01", "I03-02", "I03-03", "I03-04", "I03-05", "I03-20", "I03-30", "I03-31", "I03-32", "I03-33", "I03-34", "I03-35", "I03-36", "I03-36", "I03-37", "I03-40", "I03-41", "I03-42", "I03-43", "I03-50", "I03-50", "I04-00", "I04-10", "I04-20", "I04-30", "I04-30", "I04-50", "I04-60", "I04-70", "I05-00", "I05-10")

values <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)

df <- data.frame(values=values, test=test)
```

Let's test revalue with 115 entries

```
df$test <- revalue(df$test, c("H07-24"="H07-24 - Mettre à disposition assistance technique", "H07-25"="H07-25 - Actions pour réclamer actions publiques à l administration", "H07-26"="H07-26 - Actions pour réclamer actions publiques à l’administration", "H07-27"="H07-27 - ", "H07-28"="H07-28 - ", "H07-29"="H07-29 - DYNAMISME - APATHIE", "H07-30"="H07-30 - Promouvoir des actions, se mobiliser - communauté active - faire des activités", "H07-31"="H07-31 - Dynamisme de la société - motivation, société active, participative (acharnement sociétal)", "H07-32"="H07-32 - Activités pour développer la société", "H07-33"="H07-33 - Dynamisme des élus - des leaders", "H07-34"="H07-34 - Intéresse pour participer dans les projets", "H07-35"="H07-35 - Sponsoriser activités", "H07-36"="H07-36 - Sponsoriser activités", "H07-37"="H07-37 - ", "H07-38"="H07-38 - ACTIONS EN COMMUN - PARTENARIAT", "H07-40"="H07-40 - Action de s engager en commun –les personnes", "H07-41"="H07-41 - Engage en commun entre les communautés", "H07-42"="H07-42 - Organisation de la société (communauté organisée)", "H07-43"="H07-43 - Travail en commun entre l autorité et les associations", "H07-44"="H07-44 - Mobiliser le partenariat", "H07-45"="H07-45 - Mobiliser le partenariat", "H07-46"="H07-46 - ", "H07-47"="H07-47 - ", "H07-48"="H07-48 - ", "H07-49"="H07-49 - SYNERGIES COLLECTIVES", "H07-50"="H07-50 - De rencontre social, se réunir", "H07-51"="H07-51 - Donner d empowerment (habiliter qqun à faire qqch) (capacitar)", "H07-52"="H07-52 - Participation dans les réunions, les activités - s opposer", "H07-53"="H07-53 - Promouvoir les débats", "H07-54"="H07-54 - Promouvoir les débats", "H07-55"="H07-55 - ", "H07-56"="H07-56 - ", "H07-57"="H07-57 - ENGAGEMENTS COLLECTIFS - ASSOC", "H07-60"="H07-60 - S associer - s organiser en associations - Avoir une association", "H07-61"="H07-61 - Avoir des réunions - participer dans l association", "H07-62"="H07-62 - Participation de la communauté dans l association", "H07-63"="H07-63 - Collaboration entre les associations (et ente les associations et la communauté)", "H07-64"="H07-64 - Initiative associatif, participation des associés", "H07-65"="H07-65 - Paiement des cotisations sociétales", "H07-66"="H07-66 - Cadre directive des associations", "H07-67"="H07-67 - Construction d un siège social", "H07-68"="H07-68 - Organisation - gestion de l association (ACD)", "H07-69"="H07-69 - PROMOUVOIR - ORGANISER - DÉVELOPPER ACTIVITÉS- FESTIVES", "H07-70"="H07-70 - PROMOUVOIR / ORGANISER / DÉVELOPPER ACTIVITÉS/ FESTIVES", "H07-71"="H07-71 - ", "H07-72"="H07-72 - ", "H07-73"="H07-73 - ", "H07-74"="H07-74 - ", "H07-75"="H07-75 - RÉFLEXION SOCIALE - FAIRE DIAGNOSTIC SOCIÉTAL", "H07-80"="H07-80 - Être capable d identifier les problèmes sociaux", "H07-81"="H07-81 - Faire des comparaisons", "H07-82"="H07-82 - Réflexion sur les problèmes sociaux", "H07-83"="H07-83 - Permettre les actions qui portent bonheur à la société", "H07-84"="H07-84 - Profiter des ressources communautaires pour se développer", "H07-85"="H07-85 - Conscientisation sociale", "H07-86"="H07-86 - Conscientisation sociale", "H07-90"="H07-90 - ", "H07-91"="H07-91 - ", "H07-92"="H07-92 - ", "H07-93"="H07-93 - RELATIONS DANS LA SOCIÉTÉ", "I00-00"="I00-00 - RELATIONS DE GENRE", "I01-00"="I01-00 - DISCRIMINATIONS BASÉES SUR LE GENRE", "I01-10"="I01-10 - Discrimination directe", "I01-11"="I01-11 - Discrimination  structurelle", "I01-12"="I01-12 - Plafond de verre", "I01-13"="I01-13 - MANQUE DE RESPECT", "I01-20"="I01-20 - Mépris", "I01-21"="I01-21 - Préjugé", "I01-22"="I01-22 - Ne pas reconnaître autrui", "I01-23"="I01-23 - Stigmatisation", "I01-24"="I01-24 - RELATIONS ENTRE LES GÉNÉRATIONS", "I02-00"="I02-00 - MODALITÉS DES RELATIONS ENTRE LES GÉNÉRATIONS", "I02-10"="I02-10 - RELATIONS MUTUELLES ENTRE GÉNÉRATIONS", "I02-10"="I02-10 - Soutien mutuel", "I02-11"="I02-11 - Respect mutuel", "I02-12"="I02-12 - ATTITUDE D UNE GÉNÉRATION À L AUTRE", "I02-20"="I02-20 - Respect mutuel", "I02-21"="I02-21 - Support mutuel", "I02-22"="I02-22 - Préjugés mutuels", "I02-23"="I02-23 - Confiance réciproque", "I02-24"="I02-24 - GENERATIONS CONTRACT", "I02-40"="I02-40 - FOSSÉ GÉNÉRATIONNEL", "I02-40"="I02-40 - RELATIONS ENTRE CULTURES", "I03-00"="I03-00 - Préjugés", "I03-01"="I03-01 - Dialogue interculturel", "I03-02"="I03-02 - Non reconnaissance", "I03-03"="I03-03 - Discrimination", "I03-04"="I03-04 - Mépris, dédain, être hautain", "I03-05"="I03-05 - DIALOGUE INTER-RELIGIEUX", "I03-20"="I03-20 - PROBLÈMES DE LANGAGE", "I03-30"="I03-30 - Statut des langues regionales", "I03-31"="I03-31 - Langues minoritaires", "I03-32"="I03-32 - Statut de la deuxième langue", "I03-33"="I03-33 - Relations entre la langue maternelle et la deuxième langue", "I03-34"="I03-34 - Assimilation linguistique", "I03-35"="I03-35 - Perte de la langue maternelle", "I03-36"="I03-36 - Bilinguism", "I03-36"="I03-36 - Non maîtrise des langues natives et secondes", "I03-37"="I03-37 - ENSEIGNEMENT DES LANGUES", "I03-40"="I03-40 - Enseignement de la langue maternelle", "I03-41"="I03-41 - Enseignement des langues étrangères", "I03-42"="I03-42 - Enseignement de la deuxième langue", "I03-43"="I03-43 - OUVERTURE ET TOLÉRANCE DANS LE DOM. DE LA LANGUE", "I03-50"="I03-50 - SOUTIEN EN CAS DE DIFFICULTÉS DE LANGUE", "I03-50"="I03-50 - RELATIONS ENTRE CLASSES SOCIALES", "I04-00"="I04-00 - ÉCHANGES", "I04-10"="I04-10 - RESPECT MUTUEL", "I04-20"="I04-20 - SOLIDARITÉ", "I04-30"="I04-30 - MIXITÉ", "I04-30"="I04-30 - PRÉJUGÉS", "I04-50"="I04-50 - DISCRIMINATION", "I04-60"="I04-60 - STIGMATISATION", "I04-70"="I04-70 - RELATIONS LOCALES", "I05-00"="I05-00 - RELATIONS DE VOISINAGE - APPARTEMENTS", "I05-10"="I05-10 - RELATIONS DE QUARTIER"))
```

This doesn't work ! It's a bit like if somehow a " symbol got lost. There is a + prompt now, that you must exit typing """.

But if we cut this in two separate operations (which use the same arguments)

```
df$test <- revalue(df$test, c("H07-24"="H07-24 - Mettre à disposition assistance technique", "H07-25"="H07-25 - Actions pour réclamer actions publiques à l administration", "H07-26"="H07-26 - Actions pour réclamer actions publiques à l’administration", "H07-27"="H07-27 - ", "H07-28"="H07-28 - ", "H07-29"="H07-29 - DYNAMISME - APATHIE", "H07-30"="H07-30 - Promouvoir des actions, se mobiliser - communauté active - faire des activités", "H07-31"="H07-31 - Dynamisme de la société - motivation, société active, participative (acharnement sociétal)", "H07-32"="H07-32 - Activités pour développer la société", "H07-33"="H07-33 - Dynamisme des élus - des leaders", "H07-34"="H07-34 - Intéresse pour participer dans les projets", "H07-35"="H07-35 - Sponsoriser activités", "H07-36"="H07-36 - Sponsoriser activités", "H07-37"="H07-37 - ", "H07-38"="H07-38 - ACTIONS EN COMMUN - PARTENARIAT", "H07-40"="H07-40 - Action de s engager en commun –les personnes", "H07-41"="H07-41 - Engage en commun entre les communautés", "H07-42"="H07-42 - Organisation de la société (communauté organisée)", "H07-43"="H07-43 - Travail en commun entre l autorité et les associations", "H07-44"="H07-44 - Mobiliser le partenariat", "H07-45"="H07-45 - Mobiliser le partenariat", "H07-46"="H07-46 - ", "H07-47"="H07-47 - ", "H07-48"="H07-48 - ", "H07-49"="H07-49 - SYNERGIES COLLECTIVES", "H07-50"="H07-50 - De rencontre social, se réunir", "H07-51"="H07-51 - Donner d empowerment (habiliter qqun à faire qqch) (capacitar)", "H07-52"="H07-52 - Participation dans les réunions, les activités - s opposer", "H07-53"="H07-53 - Promouvoir les débats", "H07-54"="H07-54 - Promouvoir les débats", "H07-55"="H07-55 - ", "H07-56"="H07-56 - ", "H07-57"="H07-57 - ENGAGEMENTS COLLECTIFS - ASSOC", "H07-60"="H07-60 - S associer - s organiser en associations - Avoir une association", "H07-61"="H07-61 - Avoir des réunions - participer dans l association", "H07-62"="H07-62 - Participation de la communauté dans l association", "H07-63"="H07-63 - Collaboration entre les associations (et ente les associations et la communauté)", "H07-64"="H07-64 - Initiative associatif, participation des associés", "H07-65"="H07-65 - Paiement des cotisations sociétales", "H07-66"="H07-66 - Cadre directive des associations", "H07-67"="H07-67 - Construction d un siège social", "H07-68"="H07-68 - Organisation - gestion de l association (ACD)"))

df$test <- revalue(df$test, c("H07-69"="H07-69 - PROMOUVOIR - ORGANISER - DÉVELOPPER ACTIVITÉS- FESTIVES", "H07-70"="H07-70 - PROMOUVOIR / ORGANISER / DÉVELOPPER ACTIVITÉS/ FESTIVES", "H07-71"="H07-71 - ", "H07-72"="H07-72 - ", "H07-73"="H07-73 - ", "H07-74"="H07-74 - ", "H07-75"="H07-75 - RÉFLEXION SOCIALE - FAIRE DIAGNOSTIC SOCIÉTAL", "H07-80"="H07-80 - Être capable d identifier les problèmes sociaux", "H07-81"="H07-81 - Faire des comparaisons", "H07-82"="H07-82 - Réflexion sur les problèmes sociaux", "H07-83"="H07-83 - Permettre les actions qui portent bonheur à la société", "H07-84"="H07-84 - Profiter des ressources communautaires pour se développer", "H07-85"="H07-85 - Conscientisation sociale", "H07-86"="H07-86 - Conscientisation sociale", "H07-90"="H07-90 - ", "H07-91"="H07-91 - ", "H07-92"="H07-92 - ", "H07-93"="H07-93 - RELATIONS DANS LA SOCIÉTÉ", "I00-00"="I00-00 - RELATIONS DE GENRE", "I01-00"="I01-00 - DISCRIMINATIONS BASÉES SUR LE GENRE", "I01-10"="I01-10 - Discrimination directe", "I01-11"="I01-11 - Discrimination  structurelle", "I01-12"="I01-12 - Plafond de verre", "I01-13"="I01-13 - MANQUE DE RESPECT", "I01-20"="I01-20 - Mépris", "I01-21"="I01-21 - Préjugé", "I01-22"="I01-22 - Ne pas reconnaître autrui", "I01-23"="I01-23 - Stigmatisation", "I01-24"="I01-24 - RELATIONS ENTRE LES GÉNÉRATIONS", "I02-00"="I02-00 - MODALITÉS DES RELATIONS ENTRE LES GÉNÉRATIONS", "I02-10"="I02-10 - RELATIONS MUTUELLES ENTRE GÉNÉRATIONS", "I02-10"="I02-10 - Soutien mutuel", "I02-11"="I02-11 - Respect mutuel", "I02-12"="I02-12 - ATTITUDE D UNE GÉNÉRATION À L AUTRE", "I02-20"="I02-20 - Respect mutuel", "I02-21"="I02-21 - Support mutuel", "I02-22"="I02-22 - Préjugés mutuels", "I02-23"="I02-23 - Confiance réciproque", "I02-24"="I02-24 - GENERATIONS CONTRACT", "I02-40"="I02-40 - FOSSÉ GÉNÉRATIONNEL", "I02-40"="I02-40 - RELATIONS ENTRE CULTURES", "I03-00"="I03-00 - Préjugés", "I03-01"="I03-01 - Dialogue interculturel", "I03-02"="I03-02 - Non reconnaissance", "I03-03"="I03-03 - Discrimination", "I03-04"="I03-04 - Mépris, dédain, être hautain", "I03-05"="I03-05 - DIALOGUE INTER-RELIGIEUX", "I03-20"="I03-20 - PROBLÈMES DE LANGAGE", "I03-30"="I03-30 - Statut des langues regionales", "I03-31"="I03-31 - Langues minoritaires", "I03-32"="I03-32 - Statut de la deuxième langue", "I03-33"="I03-33 - Relations entre la langue maternelle et la deuxième langue", "I03-34"="I03-34 - Assimilation linguistique", "I03-35"="I03-35 - Perte de la langue maternelle", "I03-36"="I03-36 - Bilinguism", "I03-36"="I03-36 - Non maîtrise des langues natives et secondes", "I03-37"="I03-37 - ENSEIGNEMENT DES LANGUES", "I03-40"="I03-40 - Enseignement de la langue maternelle", "I03-41"="I03-41 - Enseignement des langues étrangères", "I03-42"="I03-42 - Enseignement de la deuxième langue", "I03-43"="I03-43 - OUVERTURE ET TOLÉRANCE DANS LE DOM. DE LA LANGUE", "I03-50"="I03-50 - SOUTIEN EN CAS DE DIFFICULTÉS DE LANGUE", "I03-50"="I03-50 - RELATIONS ENTRE CLASSES SOCIALES", "I04-00"="I04-00 - ÉCHANGES", "I04-10"="I04-10 - RESPECT MUTUEL", "I04-20"="I04-20 - SOLIDARITÉ", "I04-30"="I04-30 - MIXITÉ", "I04-30"="I04-30 - PRÉJUGÉS", "I04-50"="I04-50 - DISCRIMINATION", "I04-60"="I04-60 - STIGMATISATION", "I04-70"="I04-70 - RELATIONS LOCALES", "I05-00"="I05-00 - RELATIONS DE VOISINAGE - APPARTEMENTS", "I05-10"="I05-10 - RELATIONS DE QUARTIER"))
```

It works !!!

Is there a limitation in C()? In revalue()? What did I miss ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a limit of 4095 bytes per command line entered in the console, and this evidentally exceeds that. If you break your command into several lines it will work, like so:

```
df$test <- revalue(df$test, c("H07-24"="H07-24 - Mettre à disposition assistance technique", "H07-25"="H07-25 - Actions pour réclamer actions publiques à l administration", "H07-26"="H07-26 - Actions pour réclamer actions publiques à l’administration", "H07-27"="H07-27 - ", "H07-28"="H07-28 - ", "H07-29"="H07-29 - DYNAMISME - APATHIE", "H07-30"="H07-30 - Promouvoir des actions, se mobiliser - communauté active - faire des activités", "H07-31"="H07-31 - Dynamisme de la société - motivation, société active, participative (acharnement sociétal)", "H07-32"="H07-32 - Activités pour développer la société", "H07-33"="H07-33 - Dynamisme des élus - des leaders", "H07-34"="H07-34 - Intéresse pour participer dans les projets", "H07-35"="H07-35 - Sponsoriser activités", "H07-36"="H07-36 - Sponsoriser activités", "H07-37"="H07-37 - ", "H07-38"="H07-38 - ACTIONS EN COMMUN - PARTENARIAT", "H07-40"="H07-40 - Action de s engager en commun –les personnes", "H07-41"="H07-41 - Engage en commun entre les communautés", "H07-42"="H07-42 - Organisation de la société (communauté organisée)", "H07-43"="H07-43 - Travail en commun entre l autorité et les associations", "H07-44"="H07-44 - Mobiliser le partenariat", "H07-45"="H07-45 - Mobiliser le partenariat", "H07-46"="H07-46 - ", "H07-47"="H07-47 - ", "H07-48"="H07-48 - ", "H07-49"="H07-49 - SYNERGIES COLLECTIVES", "H07-50"="H07-50 - De rencontre social, se réunir", "H07-51"="H07-51 - Donner d empowerment (habiliter qqun à faire qqch) (capacitar)", "H07-52"="H07-52 - Participation dans les réunions, les activités - s opposer", "H07-53"="H07-53 - Promouvoir les débats", 
                              "H07-54"="H07-54 - Promouvoir les débats", "H07-55"="H07-55 - ", "H07-56"="H07-56 - ", "H07-57"="H07-57 - ENGAGEMENTS COLLECTIFS - ASSOC", "H07-60"="H07-60 - S associer - s organiser en associations - Avoir une association", "H07-61"="H07-61 - Avoir des réunions - participer dans l association", "H07-62"="H07-62 - Participation de la communauté dans l association", "H07-63"="H07-63 - Collaboration entre les associations (et ente les associations et la communauté)", "H07-64"="H07-64 - Initiative associatif, participation des associés", "H07-65"="H07-65 - Paiement des cotisations sociétales", "H07-66"="H07-66 - Cadre directive des associations", "H07-67"="H07-67 - Construction d un siège social", "H07-68"="H07-68 - Organisation - gestion de l association (ACD)", "H07-69"="H07-69 - PROMOUVOIR - ORGANISER - DÉVELOPPER ACTIVITÉS- FESTIVES", "H07-70"="H07-70 - PROMOUVOIR / ORGANISER / DÉVELOPPER ACTIVITÉS/ FESTIVES", "H07-71"="H07-71 - ", "H07-72"="H07-72 - ", "H07-73"="H07-73 - ", "H07-74"="H07-74 - ", "H07-75"="H07-75 - RÉFLEXION SOCIALE - FAIRE DIAGNOSTIC SOCIÉTAL", "H07-80"="H07-80 - Être capable d identifier les problèmes sociaux", "H07-81"="H07-81 - Faire des comparaisons", "H07-82"="H07-82 - Réflexion sur les problèmes sociaux", "H07-83"="H07-83 - Permettre les actions qui portent bonheur à la société", "H07-84"="H07-84 - Profiter des ressources communautaires pour se développer", "H07-85"="H07-85 - Conscientisation sociale", "H07-86"="H07-86 - Conscientisation sociale", "H07-90"="H07-90 - ", "H07-91"="H07-91 - ", "H07-92"="H07-92 - ", "H07-93"="H07-93 - RELATIONS DANS LA SOCIÉTÉ", "I00-00"="I00-00 - RELATIONS DE GENRE", "I01-00"="I01-00 - DISCRIMINATIONS BASÉES SUR LE GENRE", "I01-10"="I01-10 - Discrimination directe", "I01-11"="I01-11 - Discrimination  structurelle", "I01-12"="I01-12 - Plafond de verre", "I01-13"="I01-13 - MANQUE DE RESPECT", "I01-20"="I01-20 - Mépris", "I01-21"="I01-21 - Préjugé", "I01-22"="I01-22 - Ne pas reconnaître autrui", "I01-23"="I01-23 - Stigmatisation", "I01-24"="I01-24 - RELATIONS ENTRE LES GÉNÉRATIONS", "I02-00"="I02-00 - MODALITÉS DES RELATIONS ENTRE LES GÉNÉRATIONS", "I02-10"="I02-10 - RELATIONS MUTUELLES ENTRE GÉNÉRATIONS", "I02-10"="I02-10 - Soutien mutuel", "I02-11"="I02-11 - Respect mutuel", "I02-12"="I02-12 - ATTITUDE D UNE GÉNÉRATION À L AUTRE", "I02-20"="I02-20 - Respect mutuel", "I02-21"="I02-21 - Support mutuel", "I02-22"="I02-22 - Préjugés mutuels", "I02-23"="I02-23 - Confiance réciproque", "I02-24"="I02-24 - GENERATIONS CONTRACT", "I02-40"="I02-40 - FOSSÉ GÉNÉRATIONNEL", "I02-40"="I02-40 - RELATIONS ENTRE CULTURES", "I03-00"="I03-00 - Préjugés", "I03-01"="I03-01 - Dialogue interculturel", "I03-02"="I03-02 - Non reconnaissance", "I03-03"="I03-03 - Discrimination", "I03-04"="I03-04 - Mépris, dédain, être hautain", "I03-05"="I03-05 - DIALOGUE INTER-RELIGIEUX", "I03-20"="I03-20 - PROBLÈMES DE LANGAGE", "I03-30"="I03-30 - Statut des langues regionales", "I03-31"="I03-31 - Langues minoritaires", "I03-32"="I03-32 - Statut de la deuxième langue", "I03-33"="I03-33 - Relations entre la langue maternelle et la deuxième langue", "I03-34"="I03-34 - Assimilation linguistique", "I03-35"="I03-35 - Perte de la langue maternelle", "I03-36"="I03-36 - Bilinguism", "I03-36"="I03-36 - Non maîtrise des langues natives et secondes", 
                              "I03-37"="I03-37 - ENSEIGNEMENT DES LANGUES", "I03-40"="I03-40 - Enseignement de la langue maternelle", "I03-41"="I03-41 - Enseignement des langues étrangères", "I03-42"="I03-42 - Enseignement de la deuxième langue", "I03-43"="I03-43 - OUVERTURE ET TOLÉRANCE DANS LE DOM. DE LA LANGUE", "I03-50"="I03-50 - SOUTIEN EN CAS DE DIFFICULTÉS DE LANGUE", "I03-50"="I03-50 - RELATIONS ENTRE CLASSES SOCIALES", "I04-00"="I04-00 - ÉCHANGES", "I04-10"="I04-10 - RESPECT MUTUEL", "I04-20"="I04-20 - SOLIDARITÉ", "I04-30"="I04-30 - MIXITÉ", "I04-30"="I04-30 - PRÉJUGÉS", "I04-50"="I04-50 - DISCRIMINATION", "I04-60"="I04-60 - STIGMATISATION", "I04-70"="I04-70 - RELATIONS LOCALES", "I05-00"="I05-00 - RELATIONS DE VOISINAGE - APPARTEMENTS", "I05-10"="I05-10 - RELATIONS DE QUARTIER"))
```

Comment: OK, thanks - that explains it ! Now is there a way to perform those operation without using the console ? Source file ?